# Bucketizing a dataset in SQL over a timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm currently using redshift and I'm trying to distribute a 8M dataset into multiple buckets of 1M distributing by earliest time stamp to most recent.

ex: If my data set is 8 years of data and evenly distributed, I would expect bucket1 to be data from year0 to year1; bucket2 to be year1 to year3, and so on.

I'm also looking to build something like:

| BucketX | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bucket1 | year0 | year1 |
| Bucket2 | year1 | Year2 |

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sometimes you just need to post it to figure it out:

```
with Num as
(
select *,
    (row_number() over (order by DATE_FIELD) - 1) / 1000000 + 1 as buckets
from TABLE
)
select GroupNumber, min(DATE_FIELD) as Earliest, max(DATE_FIELD) as Latest
from Q
group by GroupNumber
```